# The meaning of target value of Leetcode Search in Rotated Sorted Array

Tags: arrays, search

The original problem is like this:

Suppose a sorted array is rotated at some pivot unknown to you beforehand.

(i.e., 0 1 2 4 5 6 7 might become 4 5 6 7 0 1 2).

You are given a target value to search. If found in the array return its index, otherwise return -1.

You may assume no duplicate exists in the array.
The link is here https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/

I don't know the meaning of the 'target value' here. Is it the value we want to find or something else?  Why it is given to me?

Comment: Any value; and it's stated it *may* or may *not* be in that array. And it is given to you so you can try and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is it the value we want to find or something else?
```

Yes, for example, if you have rotated array:
4 5 6 7 0 1 2
and you are given number `6`, you should return `2` - the index of `6` in the array (assuming indexes start from 0). If you are given number `8`, which doesn't occur in the array - return `-1`.

Comment: I got it.. I used to think finding the index where the array is rotated. I was wrong.